# How do I add this presentation outline in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

I have not seen this outline style in any of the Beamer themes.

[image]

Comment: looks like `\useoutertheme{miniframes}`

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\begin{document}

    \frame{test}

    \section{Intro}
    \subsection{}
    \frame{a}
    \frame{b}

\end{document}
```

[image]